# How to avoid EPERM error in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to move all the files outside skips folder. Currently file structure is user-app -> skips and skips have all files like android folder, ios folder, node modules etc. When I move it outside the skips folder I get EPERM error after doing react-native run-android.

See file structure below:

[image]

In below screen shot skips folder is empty I have moved all the files outside skips folder. Initially in user-app folder there were only 3 files

1) skips folder

2) .git

3) README.md

[image]

Comment: Are you running VSCode as administrator? EPERM is a permissions error.

Comment: you might try to cleaning the npm cache  `npm cache clean`

Comment: @Nisarg after moving all files of skips folder and deleting skips folder I should do npm cache clean am I right ?

Comment: @Antfish VScode is just for visuals. I am getting error during react-native run-android

Comment: @funjoker Where are you running `react-native run-android` ? In the CMD window? Try running CMD as administrator and running again.

Comment: @Antfish Check this screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/Lkgdgja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible fix for EPERM error is:

Solution 1:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

OR

Solution 2:

```
cd android
Gradlew clean
```

Try any one of the above and EPERM error will be fixed.